# Solution to differential equations governing the decay of two Radionuclides

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

- Equations:

\begin{cases}
\frac{d I(t)}{dt}&=\gamma_I R_f-\lambda_I I(t)~~~~~\text{with}~~~~~ I(0)=I_0\\
\frac{dX(t)}{dt}&=\gamma_xR_f+\lambda_II(t)-\lambda_xX(t)-F_xX(t)~~~~~\text{with}~~~~~ X(0)=X_0
\end{cases}

- where:
  "$\gamma_I,R_f,\lambda_I,\lambda_x,F_x$"  are simply numerical constants
- Solution to the first equation is:
  $$I(t)=I_0 e^{-\lambda_I t}+\frac{\gamma_I R_f}{\lambda_I}(1-e^{-\gamma_It})$$
- Obtaining:
  \begin{equation}
  X(t)=X_0 e^{-(\lambda_x+F_x)t}+e^{-(\lambda_x+F_x)t}\int_0^t e^{(\lambda_x+F_x)\tau}(\lambda_II(\tau)+\gamma_xR_f)d\tau
  \end{equation}

I was trying to solve those differential equations but with poor results. Basically, they describe a model where the population of $I(t)$ decays to a population of $X(t)$, but I had some problems deriving the $X(t)$ solution. Could you help me?

Comment: what is $F_x$ ? and do you know Laplace transform ?

Comment: @GCab Thank you for the interest, nono is only a constant, specifically the Fission Reaction Rate of the reaction. I edited the body of my question. Is only an IVP problem I would say

Comment: If I just write $c$ each time there's a constant, we have $X'=c+cX+cI$, where $I=ce^{ct}+ce^{ct}+c$, so $X'=c+cX+ce^{ct}+ce^{ct}$, an inhomogeneous linear differential equation. Can you solve those?

Comment: You've miswritten solution of first equation, there must be $\lambda_I$ instead of $\gamma_I$ in couple of places.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! Could be an idea. Unfortunately constants are different. I was thinking that the general form you get could be solved using Laplace transform but with a very important effort. Do you know another smarter way to solve this equation?

Comment: Why would I tell you a stupid solution, if I knew a smarter one? Jeez. Look, I know the constants are different, I just wanted to concentrate on the ideas and not get caught up in the notation – that's your job. I suppose you could use Laplace transform, but there's a standard way to solve equations of the form $X'=aX+f(t)$, which is what I got you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\gamma_I R_f$, $b=\lambda_I$, $c=\gamma_x R_f$, $d=\lambda_x+F_x$. Then system can be rewritten as
$$I'=a-bI, X'=c+bI-dX$$
For first equation:
$$I'=a-bI=-b\left(I-\frac{a}{b}\right)$$
Let $J=I-\frac{a}{b}$, then $$J'=-bJ \Rightarrow \frac{dJ}{J}+b\,dt=0\Rightarrow\ln J+bt={\rm const}\Rightarrow\\J=c_1\exp(-bt)\Rightarrow I=\frac{a}{b}+c_1\exp(-bt)$$
For second equation
$$X'=c+b\left(\frac{a}{b}+c_1\exp(-bt)\right)-dX=(a+c)+bc_1\exp(-bt)-dX$$
Let $X=e+f\exp(-bt)+Y$ with some $e$ and $f$, then
$$X'=-bf\exp(-bt)+Y'=(a+c)+bc_1\exp(-bt)-de-df\exp(-bt)-dY$$
Let take $e$ and $f$ such that
$$a+c=de\Rightarrow e=\frac{a+c}{d},-bf=bc_1-df \Rightarrow f=\frac{bc_1}{d-b}$$
Then
$$Y'=-dY\Rightarrow Y=c_2\exp(-dt)\Rightarrow\\
X=e+f\exp(-bt)+Y=\frac{a+c}{d}+\frac{bc_1}{d-b}\exp(-bt)+c_2\exp(-dt)$$
Constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be determined from initial conditions.

This form of solution will not work at $d=0$ or $b=d$. In this case you'll need to use some other method.

Comment: Hi thank you for the effort. But to me your solution looks a bit different than what proposed in the book. That is:

$$X(t)=X_0  e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t}+\sigma(e^{-\zeta t}-e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t})+\phi(1-e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t})$$

where $X_0,\alpha,\beta,\sigma,\zeta,\phi$ are constants

Comment: This is the same solution, it can be written as sum of three terms, one constant and two exponential.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Here's a standard technique that uses some basic linear algebra: First, relabel constants to rewrite the system as
$$\pmatrix{I\\X}' = \underbrace{\pmatrix{-\lambda&\cdot\\\lambda&-\mu}}_A\underbrace{\pmatrix{I\\X}}_{\bf u} + \underbrace{\pmatrix{a\\b}}_{\bf c} .$$

In the context of radioactive decay $\lambda > 0$ and $\mu > 0$, so $A$ is invertible, and hence we can write our equation as $${\bf u}' = A ({\bf u} + A^{-1} {\bf c}),$$
suggesting the change of variables ${\bf v} := {\bf u} + A^{-1} b$, so that
$${\bf v}' = A{\bf v} .$$
Then, the solutions of the system are ${\bf v} = \exp (A t) {\bf v}_0$, where ${\bf v}_0 := \bf{v}(0)$.

> In terms of the original quantities $I, X, a, b$, our solution is $$\pmatrix{I(t)\\X(t)} = \exp (At) \left(\pmatrix{I_0\\X_0} + \pmatrix{-\frac{1}{\lambda} & \cdot \\-\frac{1}{\mu} & -\frac{1}{\mu}} \pmatrix{a\\b}\right) - \pmatrix{-\frac{1}{\lambda} & \cdot \\-\frac{1}{\mu} & -\frac{1}{\mu}} \pmatrix{a\\b} .$$ (**Remark** The quantity $$\pmatrix{I_{\rm eq}\\X_{\rm eq}} := \pmatrix{\frac{1}{\lambda} & \cdot \\\frac{1}{\mu} & \frac{1}{\mu}} \pmatrix{a\\b} = \pmatrix{\frac{\lambda}{a}\\\frac{a + b}{\mu}}$$ is the (sole) equilibrium solution of the system, and we can optionally write our solution as $$\pmatrix{I(t)\\X(t)} = \exp (At) \left(\pmatrix{I_0\\X_0} - \pmatrix{I_{\rm eq}\\X_{\rm eq}}\right) + \pmatrix{I_{\rm eq}\\X_{\rm eq}} .)$$ Now, the form of $\exp A t$ depends on the Jordan normal form of $A$. If $\lambda \neq \mu$ (that is, if the substances quantified by $I$ and $X$ have different half-lives), $$\exp (A t) = \pmatrix{e^{-\lambda t} & \cdot \\ \frac{\lambda}{\mu - \lambda} (e^{-\mu t} - e^{-\lambda t}) & e^{-\mu t}} ,$$ but if $\mu = \lambda$, $$\exp (A t) = e^{-\lambda t}\pmatrix{1 & \cdot \\ \lambda t & 1} .$$